# enqueue external plain JS from plugin php to add within footer of theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue an external plain JavaScript file from within my plugin php, to add within my footer of the WP theme. Is this possible?

I've tried the below, but test is failing as no alert is firing...

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: Add Footer JS
*/
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_footer_scripts' );
function my_footer_scripts(){
  ?>
  <script>alert( 'Hi Roy' ); </script> // just a test
  <?php
}
```

So basically; the JS would be at:

```
http://dev.website.com/wp-content/plugins/mykewlplugin/js/script-support.js
```

And this PHP, at:

```
http://dev.website.com/wp-content/plugins/mykewlplugin/support.php
```

And core plugin PHP/functionality at:

```
http://dev.website.com/wp-content/plugins/mykewlplugin/mykewlplugin.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your currently active theme is making use of the [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) and [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) functions, as those are required to utilize the appropriate action hooks. With that said, you should really properly enqueue your assets. Anybody else working on the project (including your future self) will be appreciative of that!

This involves utilizing the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook and the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function *(which relies on both the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer` functions)*.

The proper way to do this would be like the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_spex_footer_js' );
function no_spex_footer_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'no-spex-footer-js', '/path/to/your/file.js', array(), null, true );
}
```

Note all the passed arguments, in order:

- a **unique** handle
- the path to your actual file
- an array of dependencies by handle (if you rely on jQuery, change this to `array('jquery')`, etc.
- version of the file. I use `filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/file-name.js'` typically.
- **in_footer** - This is the important one, and determines if the file should be loaded into the header or footer.

If you're sure your theme is making use of `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`, and the file isn't working - it means your plugin isn't configured/activated properly, at which point I'd recommend another cursory glance at the [Writing A Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) documentation and the [File Header Requirements](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/).

For your specific case, something like this should get you started:

## mykewlplugin.php:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: My Kewl Plugin
     * Description: Does Kewl Things
     * Version:     0.1
     */

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_kewl_plugin_footer_js' );
    function my_kewl_plugin_footer_js(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-kewl-plugin-footer', plugins_url( '/js/script-support.js', __FILE__ ), array(), filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script-support.js', true );
    }
?>
```